# Azure Mobile Service get current table name with table object

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an insert code inside of my tables in my Mobile Service in Azure, and I want to know if there is a better way to get the name of the current table my insert script is.

Today the code of my table "ClientTest1" look like this:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

    var payload = {
        data: {
            msg: "Nivel: " + item.Nivel 
        }
    };

    request.execute({
    success: function() {
        // If the insert succeeds, send a notification.
        push.gcm.send("ClientTest1", payload, {
            success: function(pushResponse) {
                console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse, payload);
                request.respond();
                },              
            error: function (pushResponse) {
                console.log("Error Sending push:", pushResponse);
                request.respond(500, { error: pushResponse });
                }
            });
        },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log("request.execute error", err)
        request.respond();
    }
  });

}
```

I would like to have a code like this:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

    var payload = {
        data: {
            msg: "Nivel: " + item.Nivel 
        }
    };

    request.execute({
    success: function() {
        // If the insert succeeds, send a notification.
        push.gcm.send(tables.current.name, payload, {
            success: function(pushResponse) {
                console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse, payload);
                request.respond();
                },              
            error: function (pushResponse) {
                console.log("Error Sending push:", pushResponse);
                request.respond(500, { error: pushResponse });
                }
            });
        },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log("request.execute error", err)
        request.respond();
    }
  });

}
```

I would like to not need hard code each name of the table in the "tag" parameter for my push.

Does anyone know a better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `current` property of the `tables` global object, and that will return you the current table. So you can use this for the table name:

```
var tableName = tables.current.getTableName();
```

Comment: Thankyou very much my friend!

Just to give na extra help, where is the complete documentation fo find these functions?